# ncurses: ввод и вывод русского символа на экран

Tags: c, ncurses

Возникла проблема с русской кодировкой при работе с ncurses. Пытаюсь получить любой русский символ от пользователя и вывести его на экран

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  int c;

  initscr();
  noecho();
  curs_set(0);

  c = getch();
  mvprintw(0, 0, "%c", c);
  refresh();
  sleep(2);

  endwin();
  return 0;
}
```

```
gcc -g3 file.c -lncurses
```

В итоге наблюдаю пустой экран, русские символы не отображаются, а вот латиница успешно отображается. Многие советуют использовать

```
wchar_t c;
```

Но это почему-то не помогает, и на экране пусто. В `gdb` видно что `c` выглядит как что-то подобное `209 L'Ñ'`. Встречался ли кто-то с этой проблемой?

Comment: С `wchar_t` вроде бы надо использовать ncursesw. А вообще, написали бы какая ОС, какой locale по умолчанию (можно `printf("%s\n", setlocale(LC_ALL, ""));`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Многие советуют использовать `wchar_t c;`

Это правильный совет. Других адекватных способов работы с многобайтовыми локалями нет. Для широких символов в ncurses есть отдельная библиотека: `ncursesw` с отдельным набором хедеров (обычно в `/usr/include/ncursesw`). Кроме того для широких символов есть свои версии функций. Нормальной документации я не видел, но неплохой список аналогов есть [здесь](http://www2.phys.canterbury.ac.nz/dept/docs/manuals/unix/DEC_5.0a_Docs/HTML/ARH9YATE/CHNTRXXX.HTM).

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  wint_t c;

  initscr();
  noecho();
  curs_set(0);

  do {
    mvaddwstr(0, 0, L"Жмакни `ы`, дабы выйти!");
    int rc = get_wch(&c);
    if (rc==OK) {
      mvprintw(1, 0, "Символ: %lc", c);
    }
    refresh();
  } while (c != L'ы');

  endwin();
  return 0;
}
```

Сборка:

```
gcc file.c $(pkg-config ncursesw --libs --cflags)
```

---

**Примечание:**

Для `mvprintw()` аналога, который принимал бы формат в виде широкой строки (вроде `wprintf()`) нет, так что на машинах с необычной локалью (отличающейся от кодировки исходников) оно будет работать не совсем корректно. Ради большей переносимости стоит избегать функции семейства `mvprintw()` и использовать `wsprintf()` в комбинации с `mvaddwstr()`. Но IRL всё это обычно нивелируется тем, что строки с не базовыми символами не записаны в коде, а получаются от библиотеки вроде gettext.

Comment: спасибо за помощь!